# What Chapter and What Verse is this Quote

Tags: vedas, krishna, kali-yuga, sama-veda

I was reading the following online article: https://medium.com/@vaishnav_milan_mandali/scriptural-references-to-sri-chaitanya-mahaprabhu-being-avataar-of-sri-krishna-e733a323db12.

In this article, it is stated that the *Sama Veda* contains the following verse:

> tathaham krta sannyaso bhu-girvano ‘vatarisye
> tire’lakanandayah punah punah isvara-prarthitah sa-
> parivaro niralambo nirdhuteh kali-kalmasa-kavalita-
> janavalambanaya

The following is the translation:

> To deliver the people devoured by the sins of Kali-yuga, I will, accompanied by My associates, descend to the earth in a place by the Ganges shore. I will be a brahmana avadhuta sannyasi. Again and again I will chant the Holy Names of the Lord.”

**In what chapter in the *Sama Veda* can I find the above Sanskrit verse?**